# Python listing last 10 modified files and reading each line of all 10 files

Tags: python, text-parsing

I need some help listing files in a directory and reading through each file using Python.  I know how to do this using shell commands but is there a Pythonic way to do it?

I would like to:

1.) List all files in a directory.

2.) Grab the last 10 modified/latest files (preferably using a wildcard)

3.) Read through each line of all 10 files

Using shell commands I can:

```
Linux_System# ls -ltr | tail -n 10 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  999934 Jul 26 01:06 data_log.569
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  999960 Jul 26 02:05 data_log.570
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  999968 Jul 26 03:13 data_log.571
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  999741 Jul 26 04:20 data_log.572
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  999928 Jul 26 05:31 data_log.573
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  999942 Jul 26 06:45 data_log.574
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  999916 Jul 26 07:46 data_log.575
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  999862 Jul 26 08:59 data_log.576
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  999685 Jul 26 10:15 data_log.577
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  999633 Jul 26 11:26 data_log.578

Linux_System# cat data_log.{569..578}
```

Using glob I am able to list the files and open a specific file but not sure how I can list only the last 10 modified files and feed the wildcard file list to the open function.

```
import os, fnmatch, glob

files = glob.glob("data_event_log.*")
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
print("\n".join(files))

data_event_log.569
data_event_log.570
data_event_log.571
data_event_log.572
data_event_log.573
data_event_log.574
data_event_log.575
data_event_log.576
data_event_log.577
data_event_log.578

with open(data_event_log.560, 'r') as f:
    output_list = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith('Time'):
            lineRegex = re.compile(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
            a = (lineRegex.findall(line))
```

Comment: Please share the code you've written so far and specifically where you got stuck.

Comment: what do you mean by wildcard?

Comment: `for file in files[-10:]:`?

Comment: You can use [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) to get file modification time data. So you just need to sort  your fillenames list with a key function that grabs the timestamp info you want.

Comment: @PM2Ring That's already done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks alike you almost did everything already

```
import os.path, glob

files = glob.glob("data_event_log.*")
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
latest=files[-10:] # last 10 entries
print("\n".join(latest))
lineRegex = re.compile(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
for fn in latest:
    with open(fn) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('Time'):          
                a = lineRegex.findall(line)
```

Edit:

Especially if you have many files a better and simpler solution would be

```
import os.path, glob, heapq

files = glob.iglob("data_event_log.*")
latest=heapq.nlargest(10, files, key=os.path.getmtime) # last 10 entries
print("\n".join(latest))
lineRegex = re.compile(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
for fn in latest:
    with open(fn) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('Time'):          
                a = lineRegex.findall(line)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a fixed-size sorted buffer. `collections.deque` does this, albeit without the sorting. So, here's a buffer that'll do what you need, and `main` shows you how to use it

```
import bisect
import glob
import operator
import os


class Buffer:
    def __init__(self, maxlen, minmax=1, key=None):
        if key is None: key = lambda x: x
        self.key = key
        self.maxlen = maxlen
        self.buffer = []
        self.keys = []
        self.minmax = minmax  # 1 to track max values, -1 to track min values

        # iterator variables
        self.curr = 0

    def __iter__(self): return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.curr >= len(self.buffer): raise StopIteration
        self.curr += 1
        return self.buffer[self.curr-1]

    def insert(self, x):
        key = self.key(x)
        idx = bisect.bisect_left(self.keys, key)
        self.keys.insert(idx, key)
        self.buffer.insert(idx, x)
        if len(self.buffer) > self.maxlen:
            if self.minmax>0:
                self.buffer = self.buffer[-1 * self.maxlen :]
                self.keys = self.keys[-1 * self.maxlen :]
            elif self.minmax<0:
                self.buffer = self.buffer[: self.maxlen]
                self.keys = self.keys[: self.maxlen]


def main():
    dirpath = "/path/to/directory"
    modtime = lambda fpath: os.stat(fpath).st_mtime
    buffer = Buffer(10, 1, modtime)
    for fpath in glob.glob(os.path.join(dirpath, "*data_event_log.*")):
        buffer.insert(fpath)

    for fpath in buffer:
        # open the file path and print whatever
```

Comment: Looks like severe overkill, compared to basically just adding `for file in files[-10:]:` to their code. What's the advantage of this?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: The advantage is that this is constant space, whereas `files[-10:]` stores all the files, most of which will never be used. Thus, this way is far more scalable

Comment: Then I'd say using `heapq.nlargest` would still be better and a lot simpler. Btw, I think you got a bug, for example `b = Buffer(5); b.insert(2); b.insert(3); print(list(b))` prints `[3]`. Where did the `2` go?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: oh right! I forgot about `heapq`. Also, I fixed that bug. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Still buggy, for example `b = Buffer(5); b.insert(1); b.insert(2); b.insert(3); print(list(b))` prints the unsorted `[2, 3, 1]`.

Comment: Still prints `[2, 3, 1]`.

Comment: Still buggy, for example `b = Buffer(2); b.insert(1); b.insert(2); b.insert(3); print(list(b))` prints only `[3]`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: it should work now. Thanks for all the bug reports. Keep 'em coming!

Comment: Well one obvious bug is that you ignore the given `minmax` argument, and that the documentation ("1 or 0") doesn't match the actual handling (">0" and "<0").

Comment: @StefanPochmann: this is exactly why I shouldn't be writing overkill code while breaking from exam studying. But it's fun! Also, those errors are fixed now

Comment: Now `b = Buffer(2, -1); b.insert(1); b.insert(2); b.insert(3); print(list(b))` prints only `[1]`. Also, there's still at least the bug that you forgot to shrink `keys` when you shrink `buffer`. If I were to do this, I'd just store key/value **pairs** and use `bisect.insort(self.buffer, (self.key(x), x))`. And I'd use `pop()`/`pop(0)`. Also, you're offering the possibility to insert again after having used `next`, but you can't really handle it. I'm out now, though, I just agree with your latest comment that you shouldn't have done this :-P

Answer (score 0):

pythonic answer:

use `sorted()` with a lambda function, then use list slicing to get the 10 earliest or 10 latest or what have you.

```
from glob import glob
from os import stat

files = glob("*")
sorted_list = sorted(files, key=lambda x: stat(x).st_mtime)

truncated_list = sorted_list[-10:]
```